# difficulty understanding wildcards

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

```
public static void reverse(List<?> list) 
{ 
List<Object> tmp = new ArrayList<Object>(list);
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) 
{

list.set(i, tmp.get(list.size()-i-1)); // compile-time error , why ? 

}

}
```

I am learning generics . 
I know this : When a wildcard is used the ? gets replaced with the appropriate type . When reverse() method is called the ? will get replaced and since every type is a subtype of Object , there should be no error .
I am looking for a crystal clear explanation . Please help .

Comment: `List<?>` is an _unbounded_ wildcard.  This means that you can only insert `null` into the list.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/unboundedWildcards.html

Comment: You're misunderstanding `?`. It doesn't get replaced. It identifies an *unknown*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass any `List<SomeType>` to your `reverse` method as the `List<?> list` argument, and the compiler should only allow you to add elements of `SomeType` to that `List`.

For example, it could be a `List<String>`, a `List<Ineger>`, etc...

Therefore `list.set` cannot work, since the compiler doesn't know the element type that the actual `List<?> list` passed to the method supports. It doesn't know that the elements of `List<Object> tmp` originated from the same `list` (and therefore can be added to it safely).

The correct way to write your method is to define a generic type parameter:

```
public static <T> void reverse(List<T> list) 
{ 
    List<T> tmp = new ArrayList<> (list);
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)  {
        list.set(i, tmp.get(list.size()-i-1));
    }
}
```

Now the compiler knows that `list` and `tmp` both contain elements of the same type.

Comment: What is the difference between Box<?> box = new Box<> ("hello" ) ; and Box<?> box = new Box <String >("hello" );                                        
   where Box is  class  Box <T>                              
   { T t ;            
   Box (T t ) { this.t=t ; }  }

Comment: @steve I believe the former would create a `Box<Object>` (since the type of the generic parameter of `new Box<>` can't be deduced from the type of the `box` variable) and the latter a `Box<String>`.

Answer (score 0):

[Generics work in this way](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html).

Here :

```
public static void reverse(List<?> list)
```

as we don't know what the element type of `list` stands for, we cannot add objects to it.

Here :

```
List<Object> tmp = new ArrayList<Object>(list);
  ...
list.set(i, tmp.get(list.size()-i-1)); // compile-time error , why ?
```

you add `Object`s in a `List` that in the absolute could contain elements with a different type.
In your case, it is not the case as you write :

```
List<Object> tmp = new ArrayList<Object>(list);
```

But the compiler doesn't make exception by trying to understand the logic of your code.
Because otherwise it should inspect the whole code and the compiler error messages could be really complicated.
By example, suppose you `add tmp.set(0, "aa");` at a time in your code.

Answer (score 0):

`List<?>` is list of not known type, we don't know what *type* in this list, generics were introduced for remove runtime type casting exceptions and give safety. You don't be able to add any type to collection with undefined contains, because you will break it. Example if this will be allowed:

```
    List<Dog> dogs = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Dog("dog")));

    public doSomething(List<?> notKnownType) {
        notKnownType.add(new Cat("cat"));   
// if this ok or not? <?> is not known type, all types have Object as parent let's add Cat
    }

    for (Dog dog : dogs) {
        System.out.println(dog); //ClassCastException
    }
```

ClassCastExceptin because we added cat to dogs and cast every dog to cat, in runtime generics not exist
and all collections and etc. contains Object.
This line will be after compilation something like that:

```
for (Object dog : dogs) {
    System.out.println((Dog) dog); //ClassCastExceptin 
}
```

for not allow this you not be able to add something to not known type collection and get compile time error here `list.set(i, tmp.get(list.size()-i-1)); // compile-time error , why ?`